# CORS PreFlight not sending Credentials, Server wants to deny unauthenticated users

Tags: cors, preflight

## Scenario

IIS Webserver.
Not a .Net Webservice.
POSTing to Webservice.

.Net web application connecting to Webservice in a cross-domain manner.

## Requirement

Webserver needs to require authenticated active directory users with single sign-on.

It is acceptable for the pre-flight OPTIONS test to accept an authenticated request, but any other request (including the POST after the OPTIONS test) must require an authenticated user.

## Where I'm at:

I have a successful CORS cross-domain call working between the web app and the web server. I can clearly see the OPTIONS call working and then the follow-up POST call working.

## Problem:

OPTIONS call does not send credentials. To get around this we allow anonymous users at the website level. Otherwise, we get a 401 Unauthorized error.

However, once we do this the POST no longer requires authentication.  In fact, the webserver log shows that credentials are not sent in the post at all. That is unacceptable.

I need a way to either (a) force the OPTIONS call to send Active Directory credentials or (b) the webserver has to reject all unauthenticated non-OPTIONS requests.

Preferences:

For solution path (a), I'm pretty game for what it requires.

For solution path (b), would prefer an IIS setting or web.config setting.  The webserver is written in python but I suppose we could create a c# webserver code unit that would invoke the python code that does the real work on the server.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Citing the requirements in the question:

> I need a way to either (a) force the OPTIONS call to send Active Directory credentials or (b) the webserver has to reject all unauthenticaed non-OPTIONS requests.

There’s no way to force browsers to send credentials in the the `OPTIONS` call. Browsers are required to omit credentials in all `OPTIONS` preflight requests.

See first step of the algorithm in the [CORS-preflight fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch) section of the Fetch spec, which says:

> To perform a CORS-preflight fetch using request, run these steps:
>
> 1. Let preflight be a new `request` whose *method* is `OPTIONS`, *url* is request's current url, *initiator* is request's initiator, *type* is request's type, *destination* is request's destination, *origin* is request's origin, *referrer* is request's referrer, and *referrer policy* is request's referrer policy.

Every `request` also carries a [credentials mode](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-credentials-mode):

> A request has an associated **credentials mode**, which is "`omit`", "`same-origin`", or "`include`". Unless stated otherwise, it is "`omit`".

Because the first step of the CORS preflight algorithm cited above specifies no value for the `OPTIONS` request’s credentials mode, browsers must use the default "`omit`" for those requests.

Given that, you’re not going to find any way to get around this on the client (browser) side, so I guess you’re left with needing to fix it on the server side.

Comment: Thanks.  Some of the CORS articles I've read said the credentials were not sent on the options request "by default", which implies they can be sent.   

Is there a way to configure IIS to only accept anonymous option requests but to require credentials for anything else?

The only way we've found to get options to work just stops credentials from being sent at all on the post.

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about configuring IIS. I answered to just make it clear that there’s no way to get around this from the client side.

Comment: Chrome sends credentials on preflight OPTIONS requests.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer I asked for, but it's an answer that could solve the problem for some folks.

If you're getting hammered by CORS and you are just trying to do an intranet application, there's a way to turn CORS off.

It's possible to set group policies to do so.

```
Computer Configuration 
-> Administrative Templates 
   -> Windows Components
      -> Internet Explorer
         -> Internet Control Panel
            -> Security Page
               -> Intranet Zone  (and/or Trusted Sites Zone, depending)
                  -> Access data sources across domains  
                        (set to Enabled.)
```

You'll need to do the sys admin tasks of setting the policy, making sure it gets to the local box, etc.   I'm not savvy enough on the details to write that part up.  Sorry.